# Why do you need 2 Javascript files for cross-platform Cordova plugin?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In this [article here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins#CatchaboutdifferentPlatforms), I quote:

> **Catch about different Platforms** 
>   Before it comes as a surprise to you,
>   let me clarify some things. Say you are developing a Phonegap plugin
>   for 2 platforms: iOS and Android. One might assume that we need to
>   churn out: a single JavaScript file that will be used on both iOS
>   and Android; one Java file for Android One .h and One .m for iOS
>   However, in reality you will need to churn out: one Javascript file
>   for Android, along with a Java file for Android; a different Javascript
>   file for iOS, alone with pair of .h and .m file for iOS. Both
>   Javascript files can (and should) have the same interface for the
>   developer who consumes it, but the implementations of each interface
>   would be different.

Why would you need 2 Javascript files, if the native methods are all named the same? I've created an iOS plugin (with a corresponding .js file) and now that I'm creating the Android side, I can't see why I would need a separate .js for the Android side. Any ideas why they stress this for no particular reason?

Comment: Don't know about PhoneGap, but this is how it was with Titanium.  The reason is because iOS and Android have areas where they differ fundamentally.  In fact, I believe this gap to be so large that a one file fits all solution is impossible.  Here is an example I have:  In iOS a scrollview can scroll both vertically and horizontally, but on Android you have to choose one or the other.  No amount of cross platform code is going to make up for that.

Comment: You are referring to native code - which of course differentiates. The js that calls the native stuff is PhoneGap.exec("class","methodOnClass",[args]) regardless of the native implementation.

Comment: Yes, but how will you compensate for the difference in function?  Say you want a scroll view that does both.  What will you do?

Comment: In your scrollview scenario are you talking about a HTML scroll view or a native? And if native I think you are mistaken what PhoneGap does. All UI elements are expected to be within the one UIWebView.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I've used Titanium too much ><.  Forgot that PhoneGap works that way.  This is why I didn't post my comment as an answer xD.  I also missed the last word of your question "plugin".  I have no idea why they stress this.  Perhaps it is just in case someone writes an Android or iOS only plugin, or the interfaces differ slightly.

Comment: Titanium creates native controls does it?

Comment: It does, although the lack of consistent defaults in the controls is extremely irritating.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11964/discussion-between-mitch-r-and-borrrden)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it depends on what version of PhoneGap/Apache Cordova you are using. In previous version the PhoneGap.exec() method signature was different between iOS and Android. As of 1.7.0 and probably as early as 1.5.0 the method signature is the same. You should be able to use the same .js file for your plugin regardless of the platform you are running on.

```
cordova.exec(success, fail, service, action, args);
```

I will create an issue to clean up the wiki instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your concise answer.